# How to run a script automatically when the user logs out in Linux?

Tags: linux, shell

I need to implement a feature that monitors which user logs in or out of the Linux desktop. When a user logs in or out, a script needs to be run automatically to notify a daemon process which user logged in or out.

I searched in Google and found a script under /etc/profile.d will be run automatically after the user logs in.

But I didn't find a common solution that will run a script automatically when the user logs out. It looks the solution is different for different linux distribution. Such as:

> - For Ubuntu, I need to modify the file /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf

I need to support multiple Linux distributions, including: CentOS, Ubuntu, Redhat, and so on. If I use different solutions for different Linux distributions, my code will be very complicated.

I would like find a common solution for different Linux distributions. Can you please give some clues?

Comment: Are you dealing with local or remote logins?

Comment: What are you trying to do?  There may be another way to accomplish what you want.

Answer (score 0):

In bash, the ~/.bash_logout file will be executed when exiting shell.
So place in it script you want to execute

Comment: The user can modify that, or not use bash.

Comment: Thanks your reply, Flafoux.
There are two problems in your solution:
(1) I need to modify the .bash_logout for all users. It is possible that a new user is created after install my application. In this case, my code hae no chance to modify the .bash_logout;
(2) As Anfrew said, if the user doesn't use bash, the solution will not work.

Answer (score 0):

simply find out WHO's logged in and record when you first see them, and when you not longer see them.   then read the "crontab" manual page and install a process that keeps track of this

1. the basic command:   who | awk '{ print $1 }' | sort -u
2. set -- /tmp/whoseloggedin  /tmp/whoWASloggedin
3. saving the data.   ... | tee $1
4. comm -23 $1 $2 | sed "s/^/$(date) /" >> /tmp/justloggedIN
5. comm -13 $1 $2 | sed 's/^/$(date) /" >>  /tnp/justloggedOFF
6. mv $1 $2
7. sleep for a second or two, and repeat.

you might store the data in a more reliable place than "/tmp/"

Comment: Thanks your comments, Marty! That helps.


Your solution can resolve my problem, but looks a bit complicate and I am afraid of that it will affect the performance as I must create a work thread to r/w the file with high frequently.


Is there a simple solution just like put a script under a directory, then it will be run automatically when the user logout?